# How to delete version control log(history) from IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, version, controls

I copied an existing Spring(java) project and started using this copy.

But, I found that Version Control Git history of the previous project exists in my project. 
I tried to delete previous commit history, but I couldn't find how to.

Briefly, what I want to know is how to delete version control log(history) from IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete `.git` folder from your project.

Comment: Oh i didnt found your answer before, i think i solved it with your idea. but.. my working also deleted. i think deleting .git affect my project. so i feel need of studying git. thank you!